# List object tables Named Range

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

[image]

My code was running running smoothly until I added columns to a named range table. I had to reset all of the table names, thereafter, the variable referring to the tables could not be found. When I create a new table and reference the new table, the code runs. Im trying to avoid creating new tables every time. Please assist me not to break the reference when changing table names.

Error is

> Run time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

```
If ServicesLine2 = "" Then
GoTo Ne2 'Exit the loop if a mtch is not foun d
    Dim PrRange2 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim ItemR2 As Double, UnitPrice2, HrRate2
    Dim ItemRange2 As Range
    Dim PrTable2 As ListObject ''the Table Im looking for information from
    ''declare a column range  (Item number) in th table. all variables checked (PricingTableServiceLine2_10) -table name
    Set ItemRange2 = shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[Item Number]")
    ''declare a column range  (Item) in th table. (PricingTableServiceLine2_10) -table name
    Set PrRange2 = shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[Item]")

    For Each cell2 In PrRange2
        If ServicesLine2 = cell2.Value Then
'                ''Get variables in the matching row
                ItemR2 = cell2.row - shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[[#Headers],[Item]]").row
                Itemnumber = shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[Item Number]").Cells(ItemR2, 1).Value
                HrRate2 = shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[HR Rate]").Cells(ItemR2, 1).Value
                UnitPrice2 = shPrice2.Range("PricingTableServiceLine2_10[Unit Price]").Cells(ItemR2, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell2

End If
''I get the first two values but not the last
InvTable.ListColumns("Services Line 2").DataBodyRange(InvoiceR) = GooTable.ListColumns("Services Line 2").DataBodyRange(GoogleR).Value & _
" Prints"
InvTable.ListColumns("Item Number Line 2").DataBodyRange(InvoiceR) = Itemnumber

InvTable.ListColumns("Amount Line 2").DataBodyRange(InvoiceR) = PrTable2.ListColumns("Unit Price").DataBodyRange(ItemR2).Value


Ne2:
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Where do you Set shPrice2` or is that the sheet codename?

Comment: Hi @BigBen, thank you for the speedy reply. its the last line. I added am image to original post to substantiate

Comment: You never `Set PrTable2`.... you know that you can refer to `ListObject` by index too right?

Comment: @BigBen,  You were right, I hadnt set PrTable2. Also thank you for mentioning the ListObject. I just reduced my code to 3 sentences with a for loop through the table.